# Set Shuffle, No Repeating

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

I have an array for flash cards, and using *shuffle* I am outputting 15 unique cards, 3 each for 5 different categories.

What I want to do is create these card sets for about a dozen people on the same web page, but the part I can't figure out is how to make it so each complete set is unique and doesn't repeat from a set given to any other user.

A short code sample with a brief explanation would be the most helpful to me.

Here is the code I modified to my needs. Not much changed really.

```
<?php
/* original source:
 * 3d10-engine.php
 * by Duane Brien
 */

if (empty($_POST)) {
for ($i = 1; $i < 16; $i++) {
    $numbers['ALL'][] = $i;
}

$picks = array();


$letters = array ('ALL');
foreach ($letters as $letter) {
    for ($i = 0;$i < 10;$i++) {
        shuffle($numbers[$letter]);
        $chunks = array_chunk($numbers[$letter], 5);
        $cards[$i][$letter] = $chunks[0];
        if ($letter == 'N') {
            $cards[$i][$letter][2] = '  '; // Free Space
        }

    }
    foreach ($numbers[$letter] as $number) {
        $balls[] = $letter.$number;
    }
    shuffle($balls);
}

$cardsstr = serialize($cards);
$ballsstr = serialize($balls);
$picksstr = serialize($picks);

} else {
$cards = unserialize($_POST['cardsstr']);
$balls = unserialize($_POST['ballsstr']);
$picks = unserialize($_POST['picksstr']);
array_unshift($picks, array_shift($balls));

echo "<h1>Just Picked: " . $picks[0] . "</h1>";

$cardsstr = serialize($cards);
$ballsstr = serialize($balls);
$picksstr = serialize($picks);
}

?>
Picks : <?php echo implode(',', $picks) ?>
<form method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='cardsstr' value='<?php echo $cardsstr ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='ballsstr' value='<?php echo $ballsstr ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='picksstr' value='<?php echo $picksstr ?>' />
<input type='submit' name='cards' value='next number' />
</form>
<a href="3d10-engine.php">Start Over</a>
<?php

foreach ($cards as $card) {
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td></tr>";
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $card['B'][$i] . "</td><td>" .$card['I'][$i]  . "</td><td>" . $card['N'][$i] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $card['G'][$i] . "</td><td>" . $card['O'][$i] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

Comment: mind posting your current code?

Comment: Please show the code you've done so far regardless if it works or not - it would just better show what you're trying to achieve. Also [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle) looks good to me, I don't understand why it does not work for you.

Comment: seems to be a homework...

Comment: @Benoit, it's not for homework.

Comment: @Sebastian: Even if, it would not be a problem. Just say it in the question and you will get more extensive answers then explaining how things work.

Comment: @Hakre, thanks so much for your interest. Shuffle is working, but each output as a set needs to be unique, and different than the other sets on the page.

Comment: I find the code hard to read. For your bare question, this does not need a page (just a result) nor any input elements. Please reduce the code the minimum needed. Also I read *Bingo* there, so probably you are following known rules (I don't play that game but others might)? If so, I would write that in your question because it might make it more clear what your *concrete* problem is. Apart from that I would say: First generate all unique sets (or as many as you might need), then (shuffle if more than needed and) pick.

Comment: And if you've taken the code from somewhere, reference the source of it.

Comment: @hakre As I said I took the code for a game, and modified it for flash cards. Really only the numbers and names have changed, and the code is at a bare minumum. The only extra code is for number picks, which I removed. I just uploaded this code to http://redresistor.net/bingo2.php I will be able to upload my modified code once I can find the cord to my laptop.

Comment: @HankyPanky Code is posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have more options in each set, random pick is enough to achieve unique final result.
I mean don't make this thing more complex.

Try this sample

```
<?php
//Initialize your 5 sets here
$numbers['B'] = range(1,15);
$numbers['I'] = range(16,30);
$numbers['N'] = range(31,45);
$numbers['G'] = range(45,60);
$numbers['O'] = range(61,75);

//My Assumption is you to pick 3 from each 

while(TRUE){
 $rand = rand(0,5);
 if(count($numbers_B) < 3 && !in_array($numbers['B'][$rand]){
   $numbers_B[] = $numbers['B'][$rand];
 }

 $rand = rand(0,5);
 if(count($numbers_I) < 3 && !in_array($numbers['I'][$rand]){
   $numbers_I[] = $numbers['I'][$rand];
 }
 $rand = rand(0,5);
 if(count($numbers_N) < 3 && !in_array($numbers['N'][$rand]){
   $numbers_N[] = $numbers['N'][$rand];
 }
 $rand = rand(0,5);
 if(count($numbers_G) < 3 && !in_array($numbers['G'][$rand]){
   $numbers_G[] = $numbers['G'][$rand];
 }
 $rand = rand(0,5);
 if(count($numbers_O) < 3 && !in_array($numbers['O'][$rand]){
   $numbers_O[] = $numbers['O'][$rand];
 }

if( count($numbers_B) == 3 && count($numbers_I) == 3 && count($numbers_N) == 3 && 

count($numbers_G) == 3 && count($numbers_O) == 3 ){
  break;
 }
    }
    $result = $numbers_B + $numbers_I + $numbers_N + $numbers_G + $numbers_O; ?>
```

Here $result value should be unique, And I consider number of sets is constant. If it is dynamic, then try the same logic with two dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks, this is a huge help. I will try out the sample. I'm not intentionally making things complex, I just don't know any other way. The flash cards will be words, so I guess I need to map the random numbers to my word list using variables?

Comment: Thanks for effort it's much appreciated, but after experimenting with your code, I don't think this is a good solution. I had to fix a number of errors in order to get the above code to work. For some reason each array adds itself to the previous one. See sample here: http://redresistor.net/bringo.php And the B array has all values set to '1'.

I think my original code looks more complex only because it contains the HTML formatting and number picker. Remove that and it's not any more complex than yours. Unfortunately the duplicate problem remains, so I apolgize I can't accept your answer.

Comment: Ok, just realized this code had a different number range for each letter. No wonder I was confused. However, B array only outputs 1 for some reason. I will do some more debugging. Thanks.

Comment: @Sebatian I didn't execute the code. My intention is just give an idea to do random pick. I was focusing loop, you have written nested loop in above code to make unique set. That thing i want remove, since i don't know entire logic, I just gave a general idea to achieve your goal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just store the prepared sets in an array and then check each shuffle if it exists in the array using the already (in_array function)  or not, if it does then shuffle again.

Comment: And if this creates an endless loop?

Comment: @hakre to be endless it would have to be a very short string or a ver large numbre of players.

Comment: @InGodITrust - I would have to multiply out every possible combination, and store those as a prepared set inside an array, and then remove it after being used. Is this what you are saying?